# Xamarin.iOS NavigationController.SetToolbarHidden = false not working correctly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar

What i want to do:
I want the native iOS `Navigation toolbar` to be visible as you can see in this picture (has the old iOS-style, but it serves as illustrative material):
[image]

But my problem is, that the native `UINavigationController` toolbar is covering the whole screen.

To reproduce my problem i created a simple Blank crossplatform (Android and iOS) app with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 on Windows.
First thing i did was to display the `MainPage` in a `NavigationPage` (Which is needed for the MainPage to be displayed in a NavigationController), so i changed the code in the App.xaml.cs from

```
MainPage = new MainPage();
```

to this

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

To make the problem more visible, i added following line to the MainPage.xaml.cs constructor.

```
BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
```

Now i added a custom renderer for the `MainPage`.
The custom renderer looks exactly like this

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(MainPageRenderer))]

namespace App1.iOS {
    class MainPageRenderer : PageRenderer {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated) {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            NavigationController.SetToolbarHidden(false, animated);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when i start the app on the iPhone simulator it looks like this (Toolbar covers the whole screen):

[image]

Comment: What u want to achieve, you want navigation controller or you don't ?

Could you try with setting both thing.
 NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(true, true);
                        NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;

Comment: I want to have the bottom toolbar of the native iOS UINavigationController to be visible. The navigation bar on top was already visible before calling `NavigationController.SetToolbarHidden(false, animated)`

Comment: Try to use TabBarController.TabBar.Hidden = false;

Comment: I don't use a TabBarController but a NavigationController. Calling `TabBarController.TabBar.Hidden` will cause a `NullReferenceException`.